# Why sound not play?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, swfobject

Good day.

Code:

```
<object width="500" height="500" id="ItemEditAnimationObject" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
        <param value="./Flash/1380312474.swf" name="movie">
        <param value="" name="wmode">
        <param value="false" name="loop">
        <param value="true" name="play"> 
        <param value="high" name="quality">
        <param value="#F0F8FF" name="bgcolor">
        <param value="./Sound/1380312474.wav" name="movie">

        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object width="500" height="500" id="ItemEditAnimationObject" data="./Flash/1380312474.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <param value="" name="wmode">
        <param value="false" name="loop">
        <param value="true" name="play"> 
        <param value="high" name="quality">
        <param value="#F0F8FF" name="bgcolor">
        <param value="./Sound/1380312474.wav" name="movie">

        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->

      </object>
```

When start animation sound should play too but it not work...

Why sound not play ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including a reference to a wav file as a parameter in the object embed tags is not enough to play it back in the browser. I suggest you do one of two things:

1. Embed the sound file within the Flash animation and let Flash play
   it back. Note that you'll need to convert it to mp3 as Flash doesn't
   support wav (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html)).
2. Use the [HTML5 audio tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio). Note that not all browsers support the wav format, so you may want to consider converting it (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats))

Comment: tell me please what you think when said "Embed the sound file within the Flash animation and let Flash play it back". sorry, but i dont understand you.
P.S.: i can add sound only how parameter...

Comment: Read this - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7ce8a.html

Comment: i can not edit flash - i have swfobject (test.swf) and sound (test.wav). And me need play test.wav when start swf...

Comment: You could create a separate Flash file just to play the audio. Or use the HTML5 audio tag. Either way, you probably want to convert the audio to another format.

Comment: Read the links in my answer. If you don't want to convert the audio you can't use Flash to play it back. If you use the HTML5 audio tag, your audio will only play back in modern browsers which support wav as a format.

Comment: Flash supports mp3. Have a look at the link I posted in my comment above.